# Apply filteredArrayUsingPredicate on specific column of a multidimensional NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nsmutablearray, nspredicate

I have a multidimensional mutable array that contains various objects in each dimension.

Position 1 = foodID int, Position 2 = itemName NSString

ie.

```
   Row 1     [1, "Jif"];    
   Row 2     [2, "Skippy"];
   Row 3     [3, "Peter Pan"];
```

When I try to use the following code below it throws an exception because it tries to evaluate position 1 as a string

```
//---get all Peanut Butter Types beginning with the letter---
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF beginswith[c] %@", alphabet];    
NSArray *beginWith = [food filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

Exception

```
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Can't do a substring operation with something that isn't a string'
```

Can anyone help on how I can filter using a predicate a specific column of a multidimensional array?

There are various examples of this with NSDictionary where it can be applied to a key but I can't seem to apply this to a specific position in an array.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to find or filter the array using predicate where your main Datasource ("food") array have array kind of object. And in your Predicate formula trying to find string object but in "food" array every object have array so it was crashed and not able to filtered the array. Hope you will understand from this comments.